# Best way to execute perl script from java application

Tags: java, perl, cgi

Currently from our front end java web application, we use cgi script to trigger perl script to take any action on backend datastore. But its very slow when user takes multiple actions. Is there any way to take actions in parallel ?

I can send multiple cgi at same time to achieve this but browser allows only 6 active connection to server at a time.

Comment: You should not do this.  Rewrite that CGI script as Java.  It's excellent at managing databases.  Throw away that old code.

Comment: Thanks duffymo for your suggestion, all our backend API access  are written in perl.

Comment: Silly.  Java will scale; Perl will not.  cgi requires a new process for each request.  A Java solution will use a lightweight thread per request.  You'll be astonished at how netty scales as long as you don't have long running processes that block the event bus.  Make the switch now - you'll never reqret it.

Answer (score 0):

As @duffymo points out, it is not a good idea to try to push too many cgi calls at the same time. But maybe you don´t want your Java clients to access the database directly. Trying to answer your question, I would say that you have several courses of action.

One is to try to make the perl CGI code faster. Have you considered using Fast CGI or something similar? It usually does not require to change the perl CGI too much and you will get much faster response times. [CGI::Fast](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.9/CGI/Fast.html) for instance, only takes a little change to your CGI program:

```
while (new CGI::Fast) {

  <Your previous CGI code goes here>

}
```

What it does is leave one or more *perl* processes waiting for *http* clients so requests are handled much faster. It takes some configuring on the server side.

Another way of doing the same is [mod_perl](https://perl.apache.org/). There are other alternatives. All of them will require some changes to your *perl* code and some configuration (maybe module installation) at the server side.

The other approach could be to create a new web service (in *perl* or in any other language you feel confident) and group together client requests. Doing that you could get many calls to your legacy *perl* script with only one request.

The master web service would take one macro request which comprises many requests  and call the *perl* script as needed.

Comment: Thanks Javier, i will check mod_perl and CGI::Fast modules.